# Overriding a gem's controller method in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using a (private) gem which defines a Rails 5.2 controller. I want to override the private params permitting method in the mentioned controller to add some different params.

I tried to reference the [Rails Engine Guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers) but it doesn't actually show how to override a controller method (only a model, and the same approach doesn't seem to work for controllers.)

**Update**: Here's the decorator pattern I tried based on the aforementioned Rails guide.

1. Load the decorators (Is the `/lib` folder even loaded by Rails anymore?):

```
# MyApp/lib/private_gem/engine.rb
module PrivateGem
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace PrivateGem

    config.to_prepare do
      Dir.glob(Rails.root + "app/decorators/**/*_decorator*.rb").each do |c|
        require_dependency(c)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

2. The Decorator:

```
# MyApp/app/decorators/controllers/private_gem/users_controller_decorator.rb

PrivateGem::UsersController.class_eval do
  private

  # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:existing_param, :new_param)
  end
end
```

---

I have a working solution that I don't like. First, I load the existing class and then redefine the private method.

```
# MyApp/controllers/private_gem/users_controller.rb

load PrivateGem::Engine.root.join('app/controllers/private_gem/users_controller.rb')
PrivateGem::UsersController.class_eval do
  private

  # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:existing_param, :new_param)
  end
end
```

Is this really the best way to do this? Maybe it belongs in a different place? Should I somehow use `ActiveSupport::Concern`? It doesn't seem like idiomatic Rails to me but I have a lot to learn about how Rails is initialized and how Engines and Concerns work.

**Thanks!**

Comment: When you say `the same approach doesn't seem to work for controllers`, can you share what you tried?

Comment: @Anthony I updated the post to include what I tried from the Rails Engine guide. Thanks!

Comment: how it the routing handled? Why not just make your own `UsersController` that inherits from `PrivateGem::UsersController` and add the `user_params` there and direct the routes at that controller (this is how [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) deals with the situation)

Comment: @engineersmnky that's a good idea. the gem has a separate engine that is mounted `mount PrivateGem::Engine => '/private_gem'` and `users` is a resource there. Is there an easy way to override those routes?

Comment: lib isn't loaded by default, but you can do it in application.rb with `config.autoload_paths += %W("#{config.root}/lib)`

Comment: You should be able to just add `resources :users, path: 'private_gem/users'` (above the engine mounting) and then place your custom controller in `app/controllers/users_controller.rb` and that should override all the routes for the mounted engine for that resource.

Comment: @engineersmnky now I'm running into `Unitialized Constant User` errors (maybe due to CanCan), so I added a `User` model that inherits from `PrivateGem::User` but then it is expecting views in `app/views/users` in both MyApp and PrivateGem instead of finding them in `PrivateGem/app/views/private_gem/users`.